# First Heroku Push of Application to Heroku leads to Application Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

I am relatively new to Heroku and Rails. I have pushed a small "app" to Heroku before which worked fine.

Now I have developed a bit of a larger application on my desktop pc, which runs fine using my rails server as localhost.

When I try migrating it to Heroku I get the following message:

```
   Application Error
   =================

   An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. Please try again   in a few moments.

   If you are the application owner, check your logs for details.
```

I started looking at the log files, but they don't really tell me anything. Can someone please give me a hint on how to interpret them. I think the last to logfile lines are the ones that crash the application:

```
2013-08-12T17:54:56.944875+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.2/lib/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:224:in `block in replace_gem': can't activate bcrypt-ruby (~> 3.0.0), already activated bcrypt-ruby-3.1.1. Make sure all dependencies are added to Gemfile. (Gem::LoadError)
```

**EDIT: I've now added the complete 'heroku logs' prompt output. Any suggestions on what to look for. I'm very unfamiliar with the log output, don't really know where to start.**

**EDIT 2: Thanks for all the help so far! I've got the app working now. The following was the problem**

In my gem file I had ByCrypt linked in like this:

```
gem 'bcrypt-ruby', :require => 'bcrypt'
```

Since the Heroku logs said something about

```
can't activate bcrypt-ruby (~> 3.0.0), already activated bcrypt-ruby-3.1.1.
```

I changed my Gemfile to

```
gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0'
```

This helped! The app is now running on heroku. But I think I now have a problem with the methods using bcrypt... but I will have to investigate this seperately. Thanks for the help!

Comment: You'll need to add much more of the logfile trace for anyone to help you track down the problem.

Comment: Have you tried adding bcrypt to your Gemfile, like the logs suggest? I'm not able to tell if that's a warning or an error, but it's something you should do anyways.

Comment: can you post your Gemfile?

Comment: Did you make sure to run 'bundle install' after modifying your Gemfile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you migrated the database?

like this: heroku run rake db:migrate

if that dosn't work use this:

run heroku logs, and paste the log here

2013-08-12T17:54:56.944875+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.2/lib/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:224:in `block in replace_gem': can't activate bcrypt-ruby (~> 3.0.0), already activated bcrypt-ruby-3.1.1. Make sure all
 dependencies are added to Gemfile. (Gem::LoadError)

maybe you forgot to add a gem explicity in your gemfile,

Comment: Hi, thanks for the Answer. I have run 'rake db:migrate' so I don't think that is the error. I've also now added the full log file. Any tips on where to start to look in the log files is appreciated :-)

Comment: Yeah, thanks. It did have to do with the bcrypt gem. Apparently I was using the wrong version... I explained the solution under the EDIT2 Header in the original post.

Comment: no problem man, dont forget to mark as ansswered and thumb up !